# How can I use less disk space on system storage?

Tags: storage

When I look at my storage chart about 100 GB is devoted to system storage. Is there any way to clear some space from the system folder and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on macOS Sierra? Use  -> About This Mac -> Storage -> Manage...

I'm almost completely certain a few of those options influence the system cache among other bloats which should help you.